# Update job alert doesn't maintain the job type

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Create a new job alert by setting the job type to either **Permanent** or **Contract** optionally enter any other information and save this job alert.

Then do an **edit or unsubscribe**, when it goes to edit mode the job type goes back to **Any job type**.

It should be what was selected (either Permanent / Contract).

Also is there any plans to change this page entirely, it is very hard to read, you have all your job alerts at the bottom and it shows them all even when you are in an edit mode of a single one.  It is a very confusing looking page.

Comment: Were you still not hired by SO as QA manager? :p

Comment: I'd like to call myself the bug basher.

Comment: I'd say: You are beating the quality into SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report Jon. This page will be undergoing a re-design in the coming weeks. We're adding new functionality to provide alerts for your matches so this screen will either go away or see an overhaul.

For now, I've fixed the issue you reported and pushed it to prod.